# How to change the UIImagePickerControllerSourceType in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Hey can anybody tell me how I can change the camera view in iphone where i found to buttons like 'use' and 'retake' and 'Move to Scale'message in that window I want to add some Label on top most part.How could I do that.

Reply soon

Answer (score 0):

You question title and your actual question seem a bit different.

To change the UIImagePickerControllerSourceType just set your controller's `.sourceType` property to your desired type:

```
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary,
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
```

Now, to add a label on the picker controller, you should create your UILabel and add it to your picker's "camera overlay view" `(@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView)`. To use this feature you should be building your app for OS 3.1 or later.

In any case, it would help to take a look at the `UIImagePickerController` Class [reference](http://file:///Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_1.iPhoneLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1).